# How to convert a select dropdown into an ul dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to convert my select dropdown into an ul so that I can create a bootstrap button that will display the ul allowing for the list items to act as options.

```
<select id="sortField" onchange="refreshPage('{$pageBase}','{$searchTerm}', '{$pageNumber}', '{$CurrentFacet}')">
    <option value="default">
        Sort
    </option>

    <option value="Relevance">Relevance</option>
    <option value="Highest Rated">Highest Rated</option>
    <option value="Best Sellers">Best Sellers</option>
    <option value="New Arrivals">New Arrivals</option>
    <option value="Lowest Price">Lowest Price</option>
    <option value="Highest Price">Highest Price</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the jQuery function to convert your select is:

```
var ul = $('<ul/>');
$("#sortField option").each(function() {
$('<li/>').val(this.value).text(this.text).attr('onchange', $("#sortField").attr("onchange")).appendTo(ul);
    });
$("#sortField").replaceWith(ul);
```

Hope that's could help

bye

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what event you want this to take place on, but lets assume its a `onclick()` event. to swap the `<select></select>` element with a `<ul></ul>` element you would have to use javascript to first get them by id then swap them.

```
<script>
    function swapDropDown()
    {
        var ul = '<ul><li>...</li></ul>';
        document.getElementById( sortField ).innerHTML = ul;
    }
</script>
```

then, on your select tag, simply add `onclick = "swapDropDown()"` as an attribute